# Could we run test cases on EC2 instances and report back the result to codebuild AWS to make call of build pass/fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, pipeline, aws-codebuild

Trying to test the build using codebuild and want to run tests on independent machines (i.e. EC2 instance) and report the tests result in codebuild to make a call either build fails or pass.
Is it possible to do it via codebuild?

Comment: Hey @CodeQuestor, are you trying to make CodeBuild aware of the build failing or passing or is it for CodePipeline?

Comment: @marianogg9 yes, trying to make CodeBuild aware of the build failing or passing by running the tests and making a decision based on tests passed or fail.

Comment: You could use the `stop-build` CLI (or its equivalent in sdk, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codebuild/stop-build.html) to cancel the build run if the tests would fail. If not, then the build can run normally. Thing is you'd need some kind of wait process as you're calling these (external) tests from the build run; the build will accept an exit code to make the call to either marking the build as pass or fail.